# Returning a JSON array object from the server side in a JavaScript web socket

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, websocket

Im new to WebSockets and working on sending data from the client side to the server side and back to the client side for a basic chat app. I can send the data to the server side and parse it fine with JSON.parse but when trying to return it to the client side I get an error when trying to parse it. The error is "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" Which I believe means its not a JSON object im trying to parse. But don't understand why it changes when sending back to the client side.

Heres the Client Side script that sends the data to the server side:

```
 var userMessage = messageBox.value;
 var userId = user.value;
  
 ws.send(JSON.stringify({
   text: userMessage,
   id: userId
 }));
```

The Server side script that catches it and sends it back to the client side:

```
ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
    client.send(data);
})
```

Then back on the Client side I catch the returned data and send it to a function for display like this:

```
function showMessage(data) {
  const obj = JSON.parse(data);
  const textMessage = obj.text;
  console.log(textMessage);
}

ws.onmessage = ({ data }) => showMessage(data);
```

Comment: Try to print data to debug.

Comment: I bet if you try to print the incoming `data` on the client side, it prints something like `[object: Object]`

Comment: I get that error described in the question, unexpected token o in position 1..

Comment: If I print it on the server side with using JSON.parse I get the data object like expected.

Comment: try `console.log` before JSON.parse on Client side

Comment: On the server do - `client.send(JSON.stringify(data))`

Comment: @BigLiao If I console log the client side data I get - Blob {size: 26, type: ''}
size: 26
type: ""
[[Prototype]]: Blob

Comment: @PawanSharma when I add that to the server side and console log the returned data on the client side I get - {"type":"Buffer","data":[123,34,116,101,120,116,34,58,34,115,100,115,97,34,44,34,105,100,34,58,34,50,34,125]}

Comment: It looks like it is a buffer. Try `.toString()` method on it without stringifying and log what happens.

Comment: @PawanSharma yeah when I do toString() I get {"text":"some text","id":"1"}

Comment: Try sending that after stringifying and without stringifying

Comment: @PawanSharma ok I figured it out If I do toString() on the server side I can then do JSON parse on the client side.. If you post that as an answer ill accept it as that was my issue. Thanks mate much appreciated!

Comment: Sure, I'll post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your debug logs, it looks like it is a buffer. Try using `.toString()` method on your object and then do a `JSON.parse` on the client side.